# The difference of "remove product links" in the cart and minicart (rwd theme)

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, rwd-theme, mini-cart, delete

Looking at the remove product links I found two different below codes:

In .../checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove Item')) ?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>
```

In .../checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getAjaxDeleteUrl() ?>" 
    title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>" 
    data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>" 
    class="remove">
     <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
</a>
```

Considering the below error log we have, I'm wondering if the minicart's remove link can be the same as cart once?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:16:"Invalid form key";i:1;s:912:"#0 /Installtion path/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(616): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')
#1 /Installtion path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->ajaxDeleteAction()
#2 /Installtion path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('ajaxDelete')
#3 /Installtion path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /Installtion path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /Installtion path/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /Installtion path/index.php(83): Mage::run('mystore', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:138:"/checkout/cart/ajaxDelete/id/455909/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5kaWdpc2hvcC5maS9rb3RpLXZhcGFhLWFpa2EvdHlva2FsdXQvdHlva2FsdWplbi1ha3V0Lmh0bWw_cD0y/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:11:"mystore";}
```

Comment: have you trying to removed product in cart right?

Comment: If you mean about the error log, yes it is for removing product from cart.

Answer (score 0):

Need to copy core file `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer.php` in local  `app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer.php` **or** override block file `Renderer.php`  in local

Replace code from

```
public function getAjaxDeleteUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/ajaxDelete',
        array(
            'id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl(),
            '_secure' => $this->_getApp()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
        )
    );
}
```

To

```
public function getAjaxDeleteUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/ajaxDelete',
        array(
            'id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl(),
            '_secure' => $this->_getApp()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
        )
    )."form_key/" . Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
}
```

Comment: Now I get below after trying to delete the product from minicart window:{"qty":0,"content":"\n<div id=\"minicart-error-message\" class=\"minicart-message\"><\/div>\n<div id=\"minicart-success-message\" class=\"minicart-message\"><\/div>\n\n<div class=\"minicart-wrapper\">\n\n    <p class=\"block-subtitle\">\n        Recent toegevoegd        <a class=\"close skip-link-close\" href=\"#\" title=\"Sluiten\">&times;<\/a>\n    <\/p>\n\n                    <p class=\"empty\">Je hebt niets in je winkelwagen.<\/p>\n\n    <\/div>\n","success":1,"message":"Item was removed successfully."}

Comment: By the way above conetnt appears in browser not log file